# Why was George Clooney pulling Sandra Bullock away?

Tags: plot-explanation, gravity

There is a scene where Bullock's foot was tangled in the parachute's strings and she was holding onto the tether which Clooney is also holding onto. Clooney was still floating away, almost like he was getting blown away by wind.

How does that work? I don't understand why Clooney was still floating away after Bullock aught the tether. Eventually Clooney had to detach himself so she would be saved.